# Hosting Identity Server 3 in IIS

Tags: owin, identityserver3, iis-10

I'm trying to host Identity Server 3 as a separate application in IIS 10. I added an application with virtual path "/identity" and pointed it at my debug directory. When I try to browse to "http://localhost/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration" I get "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". The project in the debug directory runs perfectly fine as a standalone server under Visual Studio 2015. I've run out of ideas.

Incidentally, I've backed out SSL and turned off https for now in an effort to whittle down the potential issues.

Identity Server Log:

```
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-10-04 13:44:23.940 +01:00 [Warning] AuthorizationCodeStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-10-04 13:44:23.950 +01:00 [Warning] TokenHandleStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-10-04 13:44:23.952 +01:00 [Warning] ConsentStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : 2016-10-04 13:44:23.952 +01:00 [Warning] RefreshTokenStore not configured - falling back to InMemory
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2016-10-04 13:44:24.346 +01:00 [Information] {
  "Category": "Information",
  "Name": "Signing certificate validation success",
  "EventType": "Information",
  "Id": 4012,
  "Details": {
    "SigningCertificateName": "CN=identityServer",
    "SigningCertificateExpiration": "2019-12-31T23:00:00+00:00"
  },
  "Context": {
    "TimeStamp": "2016-10-04T12:44:24.2176795+00:00",
    "ProcessId": 3888,
    "MachineName": "NAME_CHANGED"
  }
}
```

IIS log:

```
2016-10-04 13:04:42 ::1 GET /identity/.well-known/openid-configuration - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/51.0.2704.79+Safari/537.36+Edge/14.14393 - 404 0 2 0
```

Any help would be appreciated. Incidentally, this is a new machine so I've installed IIS from scratch - something that always causes me no end of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to deploy the Identity Server 3 at the root of the Website (in my case Default Web Site) and not in an Application.